# How to change the default path of view files in a Rails 3 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller called `ProjectsController`. Its actions, by default, look for views inside `app/views/projects`. I'd like to change that path for all methods (`index`, `show`, `new`, `edit` etc...) in the controller.

For example:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  #I'd like to be able to do something like this
  views_path 'views/mycustomfolder'

  def index
    #some code
  end

  def show
    #some code
  end

  def new
    #some code
  end

  def edit
    #some code
  end
end
```

Please note I am not changing each method with `render` but defining a default path for all of them. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If there's no built-in method for this, perhaps you can override `render` for that controller?

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  # actions ..

  private

  def render(*args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    options[:template] = "/mycustomfolder/#{params[:action]}"
    super(*(args << options))
  end
end
```

Not sure how well this works out in practice, or if it works at all.

Comment: this actually works perfectly, with the exception that the `action` variable does not exist. However, that was not relevant for needs (i just needed to prepend a folder to the path). thank you very much!

Comment: prepend_view_path is much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 52):

See [ActionView::ViewPaths::ClassMethods#prepend_view_path](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html#method-i-prepend_view_path).

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    prepend_view_path 'app/views/mycustomfolder'
    ...
```

Comment: That will look for views in 'app/views/mycustomfolder/projects/'

Comment: how about namespaced controllers? if I had a api/v3/todos_controller.rb, it will try to look up templates at app/view/mycustomfolder/api/v3/todos/show.json.rabl instead of app/view/mycustomfolder/todos/show.json.rabl

Comment: Current location: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/ViewPaths.html#method-i-prepend_view_path (Suggested edit queue is full)

Answer (score 34):

You can do this inside your controller:

```
  def self.controller_path
    "mycustomfolder"
  end
```

Comment: Splendid, works perfectly and is imo by far the best solution to this problem.

Comment: Doing this works, but makes my RSpec controller tests not use the right controller unless I specify `use_route`, which is now deprecated in Rails 4.

Comment: Works but wrecks controller spec

Comment: Does anyone know if the problem with controller specs is a failing of this code or a failing of the way that controller specs work?  I don't know how to answer that question, but I would *think* that doing this should always work regardless of how a controller is being used.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 11):

You can add something like:

```
paths.app.views << "app/views/myspecialdir"
```

in the config/application.rb file to have rails look in another directory for view templates. The one caveat is that it'll still look for view files that match the controller. So if you have a controller named HomeController with the above config for the views it'll look for something named "app/views/myspecialdir/home/index.html.erb" to render.

Comment: this seems intuitive, but it actually results in the following error: 'undefined local variable or method `paths' for ApplicationController:Class' - any ideas?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? I've tried this in rails 3.0.x adding this line within the class Application < Rails::Application block in the config/application.rb with no issues.

Comment: For the record, I assume `path.app.views.unshift("views/myspecialdir")` would work. I.e. add your own special entry to the beginning of the array instead of appending at the end. Rails probably looks up matches from the beginning of the array.

Comment: The above didn't work for me but this did: `paths['app/views'] << "app/views/myspecialdir"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default path for all your views at app level, you could do something like following -

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_views

  private

  def set_views
    prepend_view_path "#{Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'new_views')}"
  end
end
```

And write all your views in the folder `new_views` following the same directory structure as original.

> P.S. - This answer is inspired from [@mmell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791213/4675524)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer no longer works for me. After much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I've managed to find that if `render` is not called in the action, then the [`default_render`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_render) method is called. In my case, I needed to override the `default_render` message in my controller as follows:

```
def default_render
  render "path/to/views/#{action_name.to_s}"
end
```