# How to set cookies when log in/out with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for rails 3 application. For page caching, I need to set cookies for log in/out info.

What's the simplest way to set cookies when log in/out occurrs with Devise? I read 'how to customize controller' part but it seems to be a lot of work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It actually wouldn't be too hard to extend the devise SessionsController to add cookies on log in and log out, you could create a controller similar to this:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    cookies[:sign_in] = "Sign in info you want to store"
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    cookies[:sign_out] = "Sign out info you want to store"
    super
  end
end
```

Then you would have to add the following to your routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

That should get you most of the way there.

Comment: You can use the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller to use the original views.

Comment: Cookies are not set in iframe. After logged in, it redirects me on the login page in `Ecwid` embedded application.

Comment: you set the cookie before super - cant it be the user is not authenticated eventually (e.g. bad password)? thanks a lot

Answer (score 24):

Since Devise is based on Warden, another solution is to use Warden's callbacks, e.g in your devise.rb:

```
  Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
    auth.cookies[:signed_in] = 1
  end

  Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
    auth.cookies.delete :signed_in
  end
```

Comment: Nice way to set a cookie for signed_in control. I tried with SessionsController as stated in accepted answer, it worked too, but it was not setting up the cookie right after the user resets its password with 'forgot password' method. It worked as expected using Warden callbacks!

Comment: This is much more effective.  Handles situations such as logging in through omniauth or when a user updates their password and needs to be signed in again.

Comment: @karlrosaen ~ `auth.cookies` is no longer supported

Comment: This worked wonders for me. The other solutions to this question had no effect in my app.

Comment: What should be used now that auth.cookies is not available?

Comment: @rolandjitsu Do you know what should be used instead since auth.cookies is no longer supported?

Comment: @xiaopang Sorry, but I haven't used it either in a while, so I have no clue.

Comment: This method still works. I don't know if they added it back, but @roland is incorrect here. auth.cookies is still available.

Comment: I am also not seeing auth.cookies in version 1.2.3 or 1.2.7.

Comment: I am using just warden, not devise, not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from @karl-rosaen answer this solution create a new initializer or add to the end of your devise.rb initializer.

This will add the cookie to remember the email if remember me options is set, if not it will delete the cookie

```
Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
  if user.remember_me
    auth.cookies[:email] = {value: user.email, expires: 2.weeks.from_now}
  else
    auth.cookies.delete :email
  end
end
```