# Change directory for views in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible, in Rails 3.1, to change the directory a controller is used to search for views? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the answer is **no**. There are workarounds like the one pointed to by odin, but they are just workarounds and they tend to be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

There was [a thread on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller) a while back that offered a solution by overriding the `render` method.