# Rails: root path for templates for a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to specify a root path for templates for a controller? Similar to how you can use `layout` method for controller layout. I dont want to do it in every action/method.

I am using **Rails v3.1**

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller