# Clean way to render STI objects without duplicating partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the complete error rails is throwing me:

Missing partial publisher_groups/publisher_group with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: blah blah blah

In the organization show view:

```
<%= render @organization.groups %>
```

In /views/groups/_group.html.erb:

```
<p><%= group.name %></p>
<p><%= group.type %></p>
```

The relationships exist in both the group model and the org model. The error references PublisherGroup. The Group model has STI of three types that as of now don't do anything but specify type. How can I get this render to behave properly as all of the @organization.group objects are subclasses of group?

Comment: try <%= render :partial => 'partial_what_you_need', :collection => @organization.groups %>

Answer (score 14):

By default trying to render an active model object tries to find a partial called `table_name/class_name`

In particular for an STI hierarchy it will look for a different template for each class. This is controlled by the `to_partial_path` instance method which returns the path to the partial

If you override that method on group

```
def to_partial_path
  'groups/group'
end
```

Then all the subclasses will use the same partial.

Answer (score 2):

Only thing I can think of is that if your model is named publisher_group, it will check for those foldes. As you instead are going with groups as the convention. If that's not the case, I suggest just specifying the path directly as an easy solution:

```
<%= render :partial => "publisher_groups/publisher_group", :collection => @organization.groups %>
```

Comment: Oh, holy crap, I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: I didn't realize it until now, but each group is actually subclassed, like PublisherGroup, etc. I assumed that they would all be handled the same because they are all actually in the group table, but I can see that is not the case now. Any ideas how to handle that cleanly?

Comment: Ah i see. I have to admit I'm not sure of the best way for this, except to try messing around with the render method as above. My experience with activerecord SIT has been pretty minimal. Not something I've had to use I suppose.

Comment: Perhaps you can overload `render` for the related controller(s) as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller).