# Use Render template instead of render action by default in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement the following behavior:
[image: Tree of the project]

You can see that i have pretty standart views structure for controller, but instead "actions" partial, i created folder which is named like an action and in them i have a partials for actions.

I Try use "prepend_view_path":

```
  def set_view_paths
    self.prepend_view_path ["#{Rails.root}/app/views/#{controller_name}/#{action_name}"]
  end
```

But rails finds next:

```
Missing template "posts/index"
in ".../app/views/posts/index"
```

I need to add somthing like that in the end of the action:

```
render template: 'index'
```

Question: 
Is there a more beautiful way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller). From reading the thread it doesn't look like there is a clean way for you to solve this problem. The only way would be to override `render`.

I'm not sure why you are putting your template files into subfolders but, if it is not providing you with any benifit, it's probably easier to move `index.html.erb`, `show.html.erb` ect out of their subfolders and just put them under `views/posts`.

This will also make it easier for other developers (and yourself, later on) because you are conforming to Rails conventions.

Comment: maybe you're right, I'm too complicate simple things. But nevertheless thanks for the link