# Rails 4 views in a directory not named for the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers that have the same actions by way of including the same module, call them CatUsersController and DogUsersController. I want the views to be shared between them, in app/views/users. I've tried using `append_view_path 'app/views/users'` in the controllers but that results in:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template cat_users/my_action, application/my_action with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
     * "/home/me/my_app/app/views"
     * "/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/swagger-ui_rails-0.1.7/app/views"
     * "/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views"
     * "/home/me/my_app/app/views/users"
```

So it starts looking in the users/ directory as desired, but it's trying to look for a nested cat_users/ directory within that that contains the view files.

I did solve this by overriding `render` like suggested in [August's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4301269/38743), but this seems like overkill:

```
def render *args
  options = args.extract_options!
  file = options[:action] || params[:action]
  options[:template] = "/users/#{file}"
  super(*(args << options))
end
```

I used to define a `controller_path` method like in [Ravenstine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25194710/38743), and that makes the controller look in the shared users/ directory for views. However, this results in my RSpec controller tests failing because they say no routes exist unless I use `use_route`, which is now deprecated in Rails 4:

```
def self.controller_path
  'users'
end
```

Is there a better way of sharing multiple templates between two controllers?

Comment: Are DogUser and CatUser inheriting from a parent class (User)? Would it make sense to have a shared UsersController? Alternatively, if partials are being re-used you can always do `render partial: 'users/form'

Comment: It appears that this method works, its just that rspec doesn't have use_route support. Is there a new alternative for `use_route`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller - see Ravenstine's answer

Comment: No common parent controller for DogUsersController and CatUsersController except for ApplicationController.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate @MaxWilliams because that's where I got my current solution of overriding `render`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4301269/38743 I specifically say I think this feels like overkill, and want to find another solution.

Comment: I said to look at a different answer, ie Ravenstine's.  The two questions are the same, no matter which answer you look at.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: Ravenstine's answer is mentioned in my question as what I used to use but no longer works because it forces me to use `use_route` in my controller tests, which is deprecated.

Comment: So it is, i beg your pardon.

Comment: Thanks! I'll explicitly link the other questions in my comment, to show the other methods of doing things that I've tried and am wanting to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like youre falling back to rails controllers auto render capability. however, you can override the functionality by specifying what template/partial to render as the last line of your controller function (instead of letting the controller implicitly render, by omitting the line)

for example, as the last line of your CatUsersController

```
render 'users/cat_users/my_action', layout: false
```

Comment: This seems less ideal than overriding `render` because it makes me explicitly render or explicitly pass `template` in all my actions, instead of in a single place in the `render` override.