# Different views for different subdomains rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Hi I am building a SAAS software with ruby on rails in which users can have different microsites just like tumblr does it.

I am able to use different CSS and JS for different subdomains by following the article

http://blog.nbostech.com/2015/09/different-theming-for-different-subdomains-domains-in-ruby-on-rails-application/

But I want to use different HTML view files based on the subdomain.Can someone please point me to the right direction on how can this be achieved. Have hit a roadblock with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the same logic as described in step 2 in the and combine it with some of answers suggested in this question:

[How to change the default path of view files in a Rails 3 controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller)

And then you could have different folders for your different sub domains.

Comment: Still trying multiple ways to make it work.. when "css_root" files are placed  "/vendor" folder an error of route not found is displayed..any ideas?